# Custom NER model extracts substring of keyword used for training

Tags: nlp, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I trained a custom NER model with more than a million sentences using the training API of OpenNlp for identifying the skill that I taught. During the testing I have found that the model identifying the skill and a substring of skill. For example, I have taught a skill 'Core Java', if the sentence have  word 'Core' then my model will identify it as a skill. I want to avoid such situation. I want only identify the whole word 'Core Java' if the whole word is there in the test sentences.

How can improve my custom model for above mentioned result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to provide more training examples.

If the only time the word `Core` appears in your training data is as part of the phrase `Core Java`, your model might learn that `Core` is part of a skill name with 100% probability, and based on what it knows that isn't wrong. To fix it, add more training data where it's used in an unrelated way. Some examples:

```
He threw away the apple core.
Core skills in math include addition and subtraction.
The core of the application is implemented in C for speed.
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful.